# Why is the subjunctive used in "Paso por una farmacia que *esté* abierta y te la compro"?

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

> De camino a casa paso por una farmacia que **esté** abierta y te la compro.

Assuming the person goes by this Pharmacy every day and it is always open at that time I'm perplexed as to why the subjective form or the verb estar is being used.

Comment: If you assume that, the sentence is absurd. The sentence means that this person is not thinking about a specific pharmacy; any open one will do.

Comment: If the person knew about this pharmacy in particular, then they would say ***la** farmacia* or ***esa** farmacia* or refer to it by its name, i.e. they'd point to a definite pharmacy, and they'd then omit the hypothetical *que esté abierta*.

Comment: Pharmacies tend to have a rotating schedule for being open after hours; in some towns, pharmacies are somewhat clustered in a commercial district.  The speaker apparently doesn't know yet which pharmacy he will visit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you are talking about a quality or condition of the pharmacy (being open). You could consider that a "hypothetical" condition ("on my way home *if* I come across an open pharmacy, I'll buy it").

Check [this website](http://www.elsubjuntivo.com/usos.html) to learn more about the uses of the subjunctive (when you should use the subjunctive instead of another verb mood)

I quote directly from the site usage and examples:

> Para hablar de las características de personas o cosas desconocidas, no concretas, hipotéticas:
>
> - Quiero comprar un departamento que **tenga** tres dormitorios.
> - Necesito una secretaria que **sepa** inglés, alemán, francés y español.
> - Busco amigos que **sean** sinceros, simpáticos y que **hablen** español.